# ID por página o por sitio?

Tags: javascript, html, css

La duda es esa, puedo repetir el id por sitio? Por ejemplo asignarle a diferentes bodys de diferentes archivos html el mismo id?

Answer (score 1):

Al navegador sólo le interesa el HTML que le pones a mostrar en un momento dado. Si estás en perros.html y ese documento tiene un elemento con ID Pepito, eso nada afecta al navegador cuando pinta gatos.html.

Lo importante es que si usas scripts JS, por ejemplo, estos están hechos teniendo en cuenta esa duplicación a través del sitio. Y así, que seas consistente.

Has probado algo? Falló? Lo bueno de estas cosas es que probarlas es fácil